# Python AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I am new to Python. Currently, I am working on a machine learning project. I wanted to re-use the model in another piece of code so I have successfully generated the pickle file and the code is as below.

```
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

sc = MinMaxScaler()
```

```
model = joblib.load('toyota_corolla_model.pkl')
x = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

train_dates = pd.to_datetime(x['Date'])
cols = list(x)[1:2]
df_for_training = x[cols].astype(float)

x_test = sc.fit_transform(df_for_training)
```

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

When I run the code, it shows the below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0b1337d9f786> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred = model.predict[x_test]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

The model training is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

# Separate dates for future plotting
train_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Variables for taining
# Select the vehicle model which need to predict price
cols = list(df)[1:2]

df_for_training = df[cols].astype(float)

df_for_plot = df_for_training.tail(500)
df_for_plot.plot.line()

# Normalize the dataset
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler = scaler.fit(df_for_training)
df_for_training_scaled = scaler.transform(df_for_training)

# Training series
trainX = []
# Prediction series
trainY = []

# Number of months we want to predict for future
n_future = 1
# Number of past months we want to use for predict the future
n_past = 14

for i in range(n_past, len(df_for_training_scaled) - n_future +1):
    trainX.append(df_for_training_scaled[i - n_past:i, 
                                         0:df_for_training.shape[1]])
    trainY.append(df_for_training_scaled[i + n_future - 1:i + n_future, 0])

# Convert trainX and trainY into arrays
trainX, trainY = np.array(trainX), np.array(trainY)

print('trainX shape == {}.'.format(trainX.shape))
print('trainY shape == {}.'.format(trainY.shape))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', 
               input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]), 
               return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(trainY.shape[1]))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

import tensorflow as tf

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, 
                    epochs=10, 
                    batch_size=10, 
                    validation_split=0.1, 
                    verbose=1)

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Forecast
# Start with the last day of training date and predict the future

# Redefining n_future to extend prediction months 
# beyond the original n_future months
n_future = 50
forecast_period_dates = pd.date_range(list(train_dates)[-1],
                                      periods = n_future, 
                                      freq = '1m').tolist()

# Forecast
forecast = model.predict(trainX[-n_future:])

# Inverse transforamtion
forecast_copies = np.repeat(forecast, df_for_training.shape[1], axis=-1)
y_pred_future = scaler.inverse_transform(forecast_copies)[:,0]

# Convert timestamp to date
forecast_dates = []
for time_i in forecast_period_dates:
  forecast_dates.append(time_i.date())

df_forecast = pd.DataFrame({'Date':np.array(forecast_dates),
                            'Toyota_corolla':y_pred_future})
df_forecast['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_forecast['Date'])

original = df[['Date', 'Toyota_corolla']]
original['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(original['Date'])
original = original.loc[original['Date'] >= '2015-1-1']

sns.lineplot(original['Date'], 
             original['Toyota_corolla'], 
             label = 'Original data')
sns.lineplot(df_forecast['Date'], 
             df_forecast['Toyota_corolla'], 
             label = 'Predicted data')
```

And this is how I generated the pickle file.

```
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = 'toyota_corolla_model.pkl'
joblib.dump(df_forecast, filename)
```

Please help.

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: The last line `y_pred = model.predict(x_test)`

Comment: `model` is a dataframe, not an sklearn model

Comment: This seems to be a problem with saving your model, not with loading the pickled object. Can you include the code for saving your model?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I have updated the question. Please refer

Comment: @PaulH I tried this one now `model = pd.read_pickle('toyota_corolla_model.pkl')`. But it shows this `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'` error.

Comment: Numpy arrays are not sklearn models

Comment: Actually, I have no idea what should I do now. Could you please tell me what to do?

Comment: save the model as a the pickle, not your dataframe or array

Comment: Please consider to ask another question on stackoverflow about *How to save my tensorflow model and sklearn preprocessing?* Loading the pickled object is not the root of your problem.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you for the advice and will do it ASAP

Answer (score 3):

You are saving the dataframe:

```
joblib.dump(df_forecast, filename)
```

Instead you need to save your model:

```
joblib.dump(<your model name here>, filename)
```

like this:

```
joblib.dump(model, filename)
```

Comment: Now it shows another error

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-ae883ac500a2> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'`

Comment: How did you save the pkl file?

Comment: import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib
filename = 'toyota_corolla_model.pkl'
joblib.dump(df_forecast, filename)

Comment: I just tried to tell you the error I got after editing my code with your solution. I'm sorry

Comment: See my corrected answer above

Comment: df_forecast is the name of my model

Comment: @AnupamaBalasooriya `df_forecast` is a dataframe, not a model

Comment: @AnupamaBalasooriya - No, *df_forecast* is not your model. Your model is named *model* and is a keras model with tensorflow backend not a sklearn model. Tensorflow has it's own `.save()` and various load methods. Your problem is to broad to be answered in this question.

Comment: This is all because of the lack of experience in machine learning. If you could tell me just a way to generate the pickle file, it will be really helpful

Comment: Please see the code I have posted above. It shows you how to do the dump. Then your load will work. But after loading you need to predict again with the loaded model

Comment: I already tried it. But still I get the error in the same line `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'`